# find all complex solutions of $z^{12}-z^6-2z^3+2=0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

How could I find all the complex solutions to: $z^{12}-z^6-2z^3+2=0$

I tried substituting $y=z^3$ to get a simpler equation and I managed to get $y-1=0$ or $y^3+y^2-2=0$, but finding all complex solutions of the latter equation was also complicated.

Comment: Why? Isn't $1$ also a root of that cubic?

Comment: after you got y you have to substitute back.... remember there are 3 qubic roots (look it up)
in total you should be able to get 12 roots (some may have higher order...) you can check your results by multiplying the linar factors... if you get your original formula, you have your results. good luck

Comment: by the way, wolfram alpha can solve this equation...  (spoiler)
  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E12-z%5E6-2z%5E3%2B2%3D0

Comment: Oh yes, completely forgot that $y=1$ is a root and $y-1$ is a factor of the cubic, which makes it easy to factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$z^{12}-z^6-2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z-1)^2(z^2+z+1)^2(z^6+2z^3+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z-1)^2=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space(z^2+z+1)^2=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z-1=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2+z+1=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2+z=-1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2+z+\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=-\frac{3}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z+\frac{1}{2}=\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^6+2z^3+2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $x=z^3$:

---

$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x^2+2x=-2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space (x+1)^2=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x+1=\pm i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x=-1\pm i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=1\space\space\vee\space\space z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\space\space\vee\space\space z^3=-1\pm i$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think you mean $z-1=0\Longleftrightarrow\ z=1$ not $z=-1$

Answer (score 5):

The equation $y^3+y^2-2$ has an obvious root: $y=1$, and it factorises as 
$y^3+y^2-2=(y-1)(y^2+2y+2)=(y-1)((y+1)^2+1)$, hence the initial equation is
$$y^4-y^2-2y+2=(y-1)^2((y+1)^2+1)=0$$
The solutions are 
$$y=1,\quad y=-1\pm\mathrm i.$$
There remains to compute the cubic roots of these numbers.